# Sort user preferences through their selections and rank

Tags: sql, sql-server

### Overview

I'm attempting to create a sorter that allows me to get only possible preferences based on the ranks of users and their preferences

I'm not really sure where to start with this. Below you'll see a SQL Fiddle of a simplified version of what I'm looking at.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40f0c5/1/0

### Initial Code

```
CREATE TABLE selections
    (
     id int,
     item_id int, 
     preference int
    );
CREATE TABLE ranks
    (
     id int, 
     rank int
    );

INSERT INTO selections
(id, item_id, preference)
VALUES
(14063, 1, 1),
(14063, 2, 2),
(14063, 3, 3),
(15026, 1, 2),
(15026, 2, 1),
(15026, 3, 3),
(25014, 1, 1),
(25014, 2, 2),
(25014, 3, 3);

INSERT INTO ranks
(id, rank)
VALUES
(14063, 1),
(15026, 2),
(25014, 3);
```

### Expected Outcome

Based on the tables below, if I run the sorter, we should see the results showing the below. Ideally, I would ONLY want to show the item the user got, based on their preference and rank.

1. 14063(1) - item(1)
2. 15026(2) - item(2)
3. 25014(3) - item(3)

Comment: What do you mean by: `Ideally, I would ONLY want to show the item the user got, based on their preference and rank.`

Comment: The result from the query would only display the list found under "Expected Outcome" and not anything else, like their other selections.

Comment: But how is the Expected Outcome generated ? Why do only have one item for each user, whereas in the top there are many items for the same user ?

Comment: It's two tables, the first table being **Selections** where the user has made their selection of the item and provided a preference for it. The second table is their **Rank**, an arbitrary list where the user has been ranked to allow their preference to carry more weight. If a user with a rank of one wants your first preference, and you're ranked two, you'll have to get your second choice, because the first user had a higher rank than you.

Ideally, you would generate the **Expected Outcome** through a query, I'm just not sure how to begin that query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to come up with a working solution for you, but it's far from perfect: using a `WHILE` loop like I'm doing here breaks one of the basic rules of SQL optimization, which is to work with set-based queries as opposed to RBAR.  That said, though, I tried coming up with a way to do this with a `CTE`, with `ROW_NUMBER()`, and with some `NOT EXISTS` queries, and failed each time because of the dual nature of the sort. My `WHILE` loops are pretty unimpressive, so hopefully someone can come along and suggest some improvements for you.  There are plenty of people out there whose righteous indignation could probably motivate a criticism or two - hopefully they'll also toss in some ideas or an answer of their own.  :)

With that cheerfully self-critical caveat, and wishing you the best of luck on performance, here's a query that will get you the desired resultset:

```
DECLARE @SortingOutcome TABLE
  (
    UserID INT,
    UserRank INT,
    ItemID INT,
    ItemPreference INT
  )


DECLARE @Looper INT = 1
DECLARE @Ender INT 
SELECT @Ender = MAX(Rank) FROM Ranks

WHILE @Looper <= @Ender
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @SortingOutcome
      (
        UserID,
        UserRank,
        ItemID,
        ItemPreference
      )
    SELECT TOP 1
        r.ID,
        rank,
        item_id,
        preference
    FROM 
        Ranks r
         INNER JOIN 
        Selections s ON 
            r.id = s.ID 
    WHERE 
        r.rank = @Looper AND
        NOT EXISTS
          (
            SELECT 1
            FROM @SortingOutcome
            WHERE ItemID = s.item_id
          )
    ORDER BY preference 

    SET @Looper = @Looper + 1
  END

SELECT * FROM @SortingOutcome
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40f0c5/5)

Comment: This actually works perfectly! And performance won't be an issue, because we'll be using this on a small dataset and just archiving the results for future reference.